# If formula for multiple arguments

Tags: excel-formula

My Argument is as follows

```
Price Range Commission
1500>=       500
1499-201      50
200-175       25
174-51        20
50-1          10
```

How can i write an IF formula for this

Answer (score 1):

This would be easier with a Table and VLOOKUP.

First create a small table using the minimum thresholds in one column with the commission in another:

[image]

Then a simple VLOOKUP will do what you want:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,A:B,2,TRUE)
```

The advantage to this method is that if the commission rates or thresholds change one does not need to change the formula just the table in which the data resides.

[image]

---

If you really want an IF function to do what you want:

```
=IF(E2<51,10,IF(E2<175,20,IF(E2<201,25,IF(E2<1500,50,500))))
```

Where E2 is the price of the good sold.

Comment: Thanks a lot its very useful. Honestly its simpler than i thought

Comment: @Chamara now that you have two answers and they worked for you, please mark the one that you used as the correct one by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only those who posed the question can do.  You can only choose one.

Comment: Do you think Vlook up is usuful because im looking for a range so i guess i can use only IF function.

Comment: With the information you provided I would use the VLOOKUP method as you are not "Hard Coding" the values in the formula.  The IF statement is doing the exact same as the VLOOKUP.

Comment: @Chamara  In addition, the table is a better route to go in my opinion as you can increase or decrease the number of ranges simply by inserting or deleting rows anywhere INBETWEEN the first and last row of the table without having to change your formula.  This makes maintenance of the spreadsheet in the future much easier.

Answer (score 0):

If prices are in column A, beginning at A1, you could copy this formula down column B, starting at B1

```
=if(A1>=1500, 500, if(A1>=201, 50, if(A1>=175, 25, if(A1>=51, 20, if(A1>=1, 10, 0)))))
```

Comment: Why did you unselect my answer?